# How to disable all cache (css, js) from htaccess directive?

Tags: apache, caching

Having this page [Page](http://www.jumpstartsap.businessnetonline.com/ADVERTISING9.COM_GEORGE/), I can't seem to find a way to really disable the cache on all sides (server & client) .

What i tryed : disabled the network http cache on firefox from about:config(even cleared cache manually) ; added a timestamp in query string in the css url `css/style.css?<?php echo time(); ?>` ;

As you can see the style.css is empty but no changes are made to the page (unless i remove link tag , the css request) . I think apache cached the file and it's sending the cached version . How can i tell apache , via htaccess , not to send the cached version of the file and allways send it from the actual source path ?

P.S. : I'm working with a remote server .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache, in general, will not cache any content, unless you use mod_proxy_cache or similar.

Your caching is probably happening somewhere else. A few things to try:

- see if you are using a proxy server, this can cache content sometimes
- doing CTRL+SHIFT+R or CTRL+F5 usually forces the browser to refetch the content even if they already have the file in local cache
- use Chrome's Network inspector or Firebug and check exactly which version of the file is being served and if the browser is sending the "If-Modified-Since" header and/or the server is sending the "Expires" header

You can also try setting the Expires directive in the Apache config, to force proxies/browsers to not keep stale copies of the file (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html).

If nothing else works, try renaming the file and see if it works. If it doesn't, your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I renamed the file and changes are visible . Where is the cache being made in your opinion ? what apache directives should i use ?

Comment: Either browser or proxy. You might have a transparent proxy installed where you are located. Check with Firebug or Chrome inspector.